# mongocxx mongosh db.currentOp BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver, debian-buster, utf8json

I use debian9 and debian10 mongocxx driver to insert data in mongodb 6.0. Then I use mongosh 1.6 for monitoring ops with **db.currentOp**. And I get an error
**BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document**.

I can switch on profiling and look for ops profiles with **db.system.profile.find**. I see, that profile, except user data, contains driver description data, like this:

'$client': {
driver: { name: 'Н\x07\x18_\x7F', version: 'kafkaclient' },
...
platform: 'networks/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`G\b\x18_\x7F',

Such driver name DONT lead to error with BSON. But sometime I see driver description data, like this:

'$client': {
driver: { name: 'Н\x07��\x7F', version: 'kafkaclient' },
...
platform: 'networks/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`G\b��\x7F'

�� - this simbols cause the BSON error for **db.system.profile.find** and **db.currentOp**.
For **db.system.profile.find** I can use **enableUtf8Validation** = false and avoid the error. But for currentOp I can't use **enableUtf8Validation**. But I should to use **db.currentOp** for ops monitoring.
I have next questions:

1. For the same OS, mongocxx driver, mongodb, mongosh..driver name data can to diff from session to session between c++ client and mongodb. Why?
2. Can I yet disable UTF8 validation for db.currentOp?
3. Why mongocxx+mongodb+debian can bourn BSON UTF8 mistake? What reason can be major: driver mongocxx, os debian, mongodb?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: The major - source of bad metadata

Answer (score 1):

Well, some investigtions have led me to next result.

1. At fact, we have 3-levels arch:
   mongosh (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) =>
   node.js driver (https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) =>
   mongodb
2. Mongosh and mongodb not know about enableUtf8Validation, but node.js - yes. Command **db.system.profile.find({},{},{enableUtf8Validation: true})** from mongosh is transfered to node.js driver. Driver send to mongodb clear **db.system.profile.find()**. Gets result - any data. And validates it or not (depends by **enableUtf8Validation**). Node.js driver is source of error **BSONError: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document**. Not mongodb, not mongosh.
3. How to fix it for **db.currentOp**? Node.js driver not let us to send  **enableUtf8Validation** with this command. But it can process options in mongodb connection string https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/. And it can get **enableUtf8Validation** in connection object https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/utf8-validation/. So, this uri format works for me:
   **mongosh mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db?enableUtf8Validation=false**
4. The question why bad data was bourned by mongocxx driver (or by mongodb) - is still actual. But **enableUtf8Validation=false** in connstr helps to bypass it for monitoring mongo ops.